Why are mathematical constants truncated differently in powershell?
I was doing some command-line math in powershell and ran into to the following curiosity.
# "{0:f64}" -f ([Math]::PI); "{0:f48}" -f ([Math]::PI)
3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

# "{0:f64}" -f ([Math]::E); "{0:f51}" -f ([Math]::E)
2.7182818284590450907955982984276488423347473144531250000000000000
2.718281828459045090795598298427648842334747314453125


Why are e and π truncated to different decimal lengths (51 vs. 48)?
And why is it not closer aligned to some even number of words or bytes (like 16,32,64)?

Note that although Pi keeps going beyond 3.141592653589793, those are just fantasy numbers, because the next digits for the true value of Pi are 2384..., but PowerShell [Math] gives you 1159....
[Math].Pi is accurate for the first 16 decimal digits, as is [Math].e.
[Math].pi (64):
3.141592653589793 1159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000
Actual Pi:
3.141592653589793 2384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923...

[Math].e (64):
2.718281828459045 0907955982984276488423347473144531250000000000000
Actual e:
2.718281828459045 2353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277...

Both are the values you get if you turn a string of the first 16 digits into a double:
(sandbox) PS C:\Users\grismar> "{0:f64}" -f [double]"3.141592653589793"
3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000
(sandbox) PS C:\Users\grismar> "{0:f64}" -f [double]"2.718281828459045"
2.7182818284590450907955982984276488423347473144531250000000000000

So they are in fact accurate for the same number of initial digits and both values cannot be trusted beyond the 16th digit.
The reason why this works out to different lengths of digit strings when converted to a float is because a float has to be defined using bits just like any number, but unlike integers we can't define every real number exactly. You can look up how floating point numbers like a double are encoded in detail elsewhere, and that will explain the length difference.
User @Daniel points out in the comments that the source code for [Math] shows e and Pi being defined with more decimals than we see in your example:
public const double E = 2.7182818284590452354;

public const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

However, these values are being assigned to double data type constants, and the double simply does not have the precision for values with that many decimals to be sufficiently accurately represented.
There is a data type that would allow this, if you really needed greater precision though:
$piDecimal = [decimal]::Parse("3.1415926535897932384626433833")
"{0:f30}" -f $piDecimal

Output:
3.141592653589793238462643383300

You'll find that trying to replace the final 300 with the even more accurate 279 won't work - that's where you run into the limits of decimal.

Very interesting about these "fantasy numbers".  Another interesting point is the source for System.Math public const double E = 2.7182818284590452354;  public const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

@Daniel, although the source uses more correct digits to define Pi, it assigns the written value to a double which simply does not have the precision to store that exact value.  I will however add a remark to the answer to that effect, as well as including an example of how to use a more exact value of Pi if needed.

What!!? That's close to insane. Why on earth would someone decide to replace a universal constant with "fantasy" numbers, especially when padding with zeros would have been light-years better?

Well, there's no decision there - it's just the floating point number that can be defined that is closest to the true mathematical value. Many number cannot be accurately represented in code using floating point representation. My favourite example is .1 + .1 + .1 in Python, but even "{0:f64}" -f .1 in PowerShell shows this. A value like 0.1 simply does not map onto an exact floating point number. Only powers of 2 and related numbers have an exact representation. Perhaps I used "fantasy" too flippantly - they are just more or less arbitrary closest values.

For example, note that 64, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.0625 all are represented perfectly accurately.

Also @not2qubit - in case this wasn't clear already - please note that this is not specific to PowerShell, or Python, or any language. It is specific to the whole concept of floating point numbers. They are an approximation of real numbers in binary, but it's just mathematically impossible to have accurate representations of real numbers in efficient binary format that can be very rapidly operated on with binary logic. Your sense of representing them as strings of decimal digits is closer to our experience of them, but just a more wasteful and expensive approximation.

Fair enough, and I should know this. But those decade old memories have somehow gotten replaced by ignorant bliss. ♻️
